# Using hibernate 4.1.7 and c3p0 in playframework

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0, classpath, c3p0

I have a play app (play 2.0.4) that uses a Java jar for all of it's database-related work (JPA/Hibernate 4.1.7/PostgreSQL). Everything worked great until I realized I was using the default connection pool, and I was occasionally getting errors that seemed to be a result of this, so I switched to c3p0. When I did that, copied the new jar into the play, I got the following exception:

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[ExceptionInInitializerError: null]]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at models.AuthenticatedUser$.auth(AuthenticatedUser.scala:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$2.apply(Application.scala:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$2.apply(Application.scala:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at play.api.data.Mapping$$anonfun$verifying$2.apply(Form.scala:452) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.data.Mapping$$anonfun$verifying$2.apply(Form.scala:451) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.data.validation.Constraint.apply(Validation.scala:21) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: persistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:901) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.xonami.rest.db.EMFactory.<clinit>(EMFactory.java:29) ~[xonami-api-0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at models.AuthenticatedUser$.auth(AuthenticatedUser.scala:67) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Application$$anonfun$2.apply(Application.scala:25) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider: org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.initializeConnectionProviderFromConfig(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:178) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.InjectionSettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(InjectionSettingsFactory.java:51) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2163) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2159) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
```

I have experimented with including the hibernate and c3p0 jars in the play libs folder to no avail (although I think I am building those into my jar). I am guessing maybe play has an older version of c3p0 that's first in the classpath? Can I take it out? How? Is something else possibly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your logs, I think that you forgot to add the `hibernate-c3p0` dependency, which can be added by editing your `project/Build.scala` file:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-c3p0" % "4.1.7.Final"
    ...
  )
```

or you can also drop it in your `lib` folder.

Comment: I guess I completely forgot how play managed dependencies since I last looked at it, and I didn't even realize. This clear it right up, Thanks!